# Is Perlin Noise a "fractal"?

Tags: terminology

I have an old Spanish CG book that calls Perlin Noise a "fractal structure". After reading [this](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/TNM022-2005/perlinnoiselinks/perlin-noise-math-faq.html) I couldn't deny it or confirm it. Is it a fractal structure? What would it Hausdorff dimension be?

Comment: This seems like a question for http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: definitely out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Perlin noise, by default, is not self-similar the way we would expect a fractal to be.  Ken Perlin seems to imply that it is not a fractal, but that it can be usefully used to make fractals!  See his slide here: http://www.noisemachine.com/talk1/21.html where he briefly mentions how one might do that.